# Merge and synonymize [thread-safe] and [thread-safety]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[thread-safety](/questions/tagged/thread-safety) has 2104 questions.  [thread-safe](/questions/tagged/thread-safe) has 64.  Can we make [thread-safe](/questions/tagged/thread-safe) a synonym of [thread-safety](/questions/tagged/thread-safety)?

As far as I can tell, the tags are being used interchangeably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Went ahead and did a retag in some downtime, so [thread-safe](/questions/tagged/thread-safe) should disappear soon. If anyone has the rep to get the synonym in place they are quite welcome to do so.